# Intersection observer only observe the bottom of my component and trigger only when all the component has disappeared

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would the top side of the component to be observed relatively to the to side of the viewport. The aim is to trigger a callback when 20% of the component is visible.

I have seen on developer.mozilla.org that by default the API observes also the target from the top of the root. You can see an example on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

So I have decided when 80% of my top component will leave the viewport to trigger a callback. Here my snippet:

```
let options = {  
            threshold: 0.8
        }
this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(()=> console.log("active intersection!"));
this.observer.observe(this.accueil.current.top.current, options);
```

But seems so far that my application only appreciate the intersection from the bottom boundary of the root.

Also,  this.accueilTop.current is a children passed to the parent in which I have implemented the intersectionObserver by transmitting the child ref to the parent component.

Snippet of the ref transferring here:

```
{React.createRef() ...}
```

parent:

```
  <Accueil ref={this.accueil} />
```

child:

```
 <div ref={this.top}/>
```

So that it,

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Code snippets aren't as useful if we can't see how they are connected. We can't see where and when it is called. It is fine to reduce it to the relevant parts but it should still be valid and complete to run on its own if possible so others can test it in a sandbox or on their machine. So please do not omit the surrounding parts like component and function definitions.

Comment: it works on sandbox, so maybe  I have a component in my application which cover the children, here the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-platform-x933g, I have some tooltip and all in the  real component that drop on the whole page when click, maybe one of theses block the interaction with the observer, or something like that

Comment: You passed the `options` to the wrong function and you need a threshold of `0.2`. See my answer with a working example.

Comment: thanks, I meant 20% of the component leaving and 80% appearing, I have corrected my post :).

Comment: Okay so did you check my answer and does that work for you?

Comment: yes, no it still doesn t works, I think there is a component in my code that prevent the intersection observer to observe from the top. Because on codesandbox.io it works, I assume there is a tooltip or other thing, I will try some options to dive down, z-index for example and other thing eventually

Comment: The `IntersectionObserver` does not care for other components. It just detects a DOM nodes position relative to the root element which defaults to the viewport. It's not like it looks onto a screen like a human does. So either the node you are tracking is not leaving the viewport or you are not observing it.

Comment: hmm.. I see, thanks, my component is in fact a nested page inside my whole website. I will try some solutions to appreciate, I think it is observed since when the bottom reaches the observer it trigger a callback, meanwhile, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2):

You can use `entry.boundingClientRect` which tells your bottom is in viewport or not. If bottom is less than 0, it's not in viewport, also if bottom is greater than window size, it's not in view port.

Also threshold check must be on each scroll when it's in viewport, slicing to each 10%.

```
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      entries.forEach(entry => { 
        const bcr = entry.boundingClientRect;
        const isBottomVisible = (bcr.bottom < window.innerHeight) && bcr.bottom;
        console.log(bcr.top, bcr.bottom, window.innerHeight, {isBottomVisible});
      });
    }, {threshold: Array(11).fill().map( (_, i) => i*.1)});
    observer.observe(this._templateContainer );
```

Comment: Works perfect, but I'm not sure if I understand the calculation of the threshold. Could you please explain ?

Comment: Ok, I believe I understood what your're doing.

Your function creates an array (I didn't know thresholds could be an array) of:

`[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6000000000000001, 0.7000000000000001, 0.8, 0.9, 1]`

Meaning, the callback is executed  when the target element enters/exits the intersection root (i.e. intersection ratio of 0), then again when its intersection ratio crosses 0.1, 0.2, etc.

Comment: What if the element is tall, and 10% is not going to fit in view?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/observe) `.observe()` only takes one argument which is the element to observe. You probably meant to pass the `options` object to the call of the constructor of the `IntersectionObserver` rather then to `.observe()`:

```
let options = {threshold: 0.2};

this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    () => console.log("active intersection!"), 
    // options must go here
    options,
);

this.observer.observe(this.accueil.current.top.current);
```

Also if your goal is to trigger the callback when 80% of your element left the viewport you actually have to set the `threshold` to `0.2`. That means the callback will be called when 20% of your element is visible which is the same as 80% being invisible.

[image: Edit frosty-smoke-pf87b]